# Generator normalisation in the covariant derivative

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, conventions

A common convention for the definition of the covariant derivative in the SM is
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu - i g_s \frac{\lambda^a}{2}G^a_\mu - \cdots
$$
where $\lambda^a$ are the Gell-Mann matrices. In this definition, we have chosen out SU(3) generators to be
$$
T^a_{\bf{3}} = \frac{\lambda^a}{2}
$$
and therefore it has the normalisation (the Dynkin index)
$$
\text{Tr}(T^a_{\bf{3}} T^b_{\bf{3}}) = S({\bf{3}})\delta^{ab} = \frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}.
$$
Suppose we want to use a different normalisation for the generators. This is the same as rescaling $T^a_{\bf{3}}$ by a factor, therefore changing how we define $g_s$ if we were to keep the form $-i g_s T^a_{\bf{3}}G_\mu^a$. It seems like if we want to make the definition of $g_s$ independent of the Dynkin index, we would need
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu - i g_s \frac{T^a_{\bf{3}}}{\sqrt{2S(\bf{3})}}G^a_\mu - \cdots.
$$
Is this correct?

If we were to consider other representations (let's say we insert an extra field charged under SU(3) into the SM Lagrangian that does not transform as $\bf{3}$), would the same apply? i.e.
$$
D_\mu = \partial_\mu - i g_s \frac{T^a_{\bf{r}}}{\sqrt{2S(\bf{r})}}G^a_\mu - \cdots
$$
such that $g_s$ appearing in all covariant derivatives in the Lagrangian can be identified as the same coupling?